# Can PostgreSQL configured as "shared nothing, parallel database" ?

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing, postgis

I googled a lot, but only relevant result came up as pg-pool.

So my question is does PostgreSQL support partitioned parallel database ?
More specifically, does it work with PostGIS ?

Comment: Try on the DBA stack, perhaps.

Comment: You're going to have to provide some sort of useful information if you expect a useful answer. Failing that, assume "no" - if you're not clear what you want to achieve it'll be a nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Postgres-XC:

http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/